# When I declare/create a variable in Perl, is it local or global by default?

Tags: perl, scope

In this example:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

$a = 4; # Is $a a local variable or a global variable?
print $a, "\n";
```

what kind of scope does *$a* have?

Comment: Check out [Coping with Scoping](http://perl.plover.com/FAQs/Namespaces.html). It's probably a bit out of date, but it will help you to see the major features of scope in Perl.

Comment: Also, add `use warnings;` and `use strict;` to the top of your Perl scripts. `use strict;` will help you catch unwanted globals.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

That particular variable `$a` is a predefined variable used with `sort`. However, if you used `$x` it would be considered

```
$main::x;
```

It is a global variable within package "main", which is the main script.

Note that if you use `use strict`, which you always should, perl will force you to be specific when using variables. In which case you cannot just use

```
$x = 4;
```

Because it will generate a fatal exception `Global symbol "$x" requires explicit package name at ...` Usually you would then use `my` or `our` to declare the variable:

```
my $x = 4;
```

However you can also use `$main::x` as long as you specify the full variable name.

Comment: The only thing special about `$a` is that it doesn't issue strict warnings. (Unlike, say, `$_`, which means `$::_` no matter which package you're in.)

Comment: I upvoted, but I'd imagine that addition of 'local' and 'our' keywords would probably also be helpful.

Answer (score 3):

[ I'm going to pretend you used `$x` instead of `$a` because `$a` is ever so slightly special (due to its use by `sort`). ]

> Is $x a local variable or a global variable?

The two kinds of variables in Perl are *lexical* and *package*.

Absent declaration<sup>[1]</sup>, variables are package variables<sup>[2]</sup>. That's what you have there. Specifically, it's a shorthand for `$main::x` (where `main` is whatever package the code is compiled in).

Package variables are global, which mean they can be seen from anywhere in the code. That said, one may need to use their full name (e.g. `$main::x`) to see them from some places.

---

1. Your question is academic as phrased since you should should *always* use `use strict;` which specifically forbids you from using undeclared variables.
2. Some variables (e.g. `$_`, `$1`, `$a`, etc) are predeclared for you, so this doesn't apply them.

Answer (score 0):

#### Use *my* or *local* for Scoping Variables

Unless declared with the [my](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/my.html) or [local](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/local.html) keywords, variables in Perl generally have global scope within the package namespace.

Comment: i don't want use my or local it consider which type of variable

Comment: @user1363308 Then it's global within the package namespace.

Comment: `local` doesn't declare variables. `local` localises an existing variable.

Comment: `local` doesn't affect the scope of variable. It just changes its value.